# SharePoint Web Part using Dynamics CRM 2011 web services

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2010, assemblies, dynamics-crm-2011, compatibility

I'm want to create some SharePoint 2010 Web Part which could retrieve data from Dynamics CRM 2011 web service. I can not add references to the CRM dlls because the web part will be using assemblies of .Net 3.5 version, and I get a troubles when I try to deploy my Web Part with assemblies of .Net 4.0 added.
Can I use these Web services without adding CRM assemblies?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a service reference which targets the WSDL-endpoint. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509052.aspx for more information.

Comment: I agree, if you can't include the assemblies this would be the way to go.